# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation when resource in url contains .txt or .t

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using MVC Spring with Jackson (actually Spring Boot). Mapping of Java bean to JSON mapping works fine unless I try to access resource with .txt or .t in name like: `http://my-service/file-info/file.txt`. Spring logs this as an error and returns 406 - Not Acceptable.

However when I change it to  `http://my-service/file-info/file.txta` it works and JSON is returned.

I guess that for some reason for resources ending .t and .txt an attempt is made to convert it maybe to text format and it fails with error.

How do I turn this Spring/Jackson behavior off?

This is my simple MVC Spring method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "file-info/{file}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<FileInfo> getFileInfo() {

    FileInfo info = new FileInfo();
    info.setName("file_name");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(info, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is REST entity class:

```
public class FileInfo {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation in exceptionhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351142/httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-could-not-find-acceptable-representation-in)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able use it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "file-info/{file}.{extension}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<FileInfo> getFileInfo() {

    FileInfo info = new FileInfo();
    info.setName("file");
    info.setExtension("extension"); // or something like that

    return new ResponseEntity<>(info, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put a / at the end of url, for example http://myservice.company.com/file-info/file.txt/

Comment: If you want to suggest somethign post comment