# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation in exceptionhandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have the following image download method in my controller (Spring 4.1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/image/{id}/{fileName}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody byte[] showImageOnId(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
    setContentType(fileName); //sets contenttype based on extention of file
    return getImage(id, fileName);
}
```

The following `ControllerAdvice` method should handle a non-existing file and return a json error response:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException e) {
    Map<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    errorMap.put("error", e.getMessage());
    return errorMap;
}
```

My JUnit test works flawless

(**EDIT** this is because of extention .bla : this also works on appserver):

```
@Test
public void testResourceNotFound() throws Exception {
    String fileName = "bla.bla";
      mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/get/image/bla/" + fileName)
            .with(httpBasic("test", "test")))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$error").value(Matchers.startsWith("Resource not found")))
            .andExpect(status().is(404));
}
```

and gives the following output:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 404
   Error message = null
         Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Content-Type=[application/json]}
    Content type = application/json
            Body = {"error":"Resource not found: bla/bla.bla"}
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

However on my appserver i get the following error message when trying to donwload non existing image:

(**EDIT** this is because of extention .jpg : this also fails on JUnit test with .jpg extention):

`ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver  - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> nl.krocket.ocr.web.controller.ExceptionController.handleResourceNotFoundException(nl.krocket.ocr.web.backing.ResourceNotFoundException)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`

I have configured messageconverters in my mvc configuration as follows:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    //objectMapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getJsonMediaTypes());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter() {
    ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter arrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
    arrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getImageMediaTypes());
    return arrayHttpMessageConverter;
}
```

What am i missing? And why is the JUnit test working?

Comment: Check the "Accept" header of your request (the "real" one, to the appserver). Does it accept both image/* and application/json? If it accepts only image/* then Spring cannot produce JSON message, because it would not be compatible with what the request accepts.

Comment: I have the following: Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: How do i change? Add to messageconverters (`setSupportedMediaTypes`)?

Comment: Is it possible/useful for the client to receive JSON when it's expecting an image? Usually when requesting an image an error response code is all the information the client needs (eg. in a web application). Try to debug where the exception is thrown, possibly `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor#writeWithMessageConverters()`, `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping#handleNoMatch` or `ServletHandlerMethodInvoker#writeWithMessageConverters`

Comment: I can handle the 404 response in my ajax call to show the error message in stead of the image, so no problem there.
The error is thrown from `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:134)`

Comment: I added json mediatype to my bytearray messageconverter but same result. Debugging is a little difficult; remote server. What to do? And why is the JUnit test working?

Comment: The extention explains why the JUnit test was working; now i need to figure out what to do with the image extention...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to decide how the media type of the response should be determined by Spring. That can be done in several ways:

- path extension (eg. /image.jpg)
- URL parameter (eg. ?format=jpg)
- HTTP Accept header (eg. Accept: image/jpg)

By default, Spring looks at the *extension* rather than the `Accept` header. This behaviour can be changed if you implement a `@Configuration` class that extends [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) (or since Spring 5.0 simply implement [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html). There you can override [`configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#configureContentNegotiation-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer-) and configure the [`ContentNegotiationConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html) to your needs, eg. by calling

```
ContentNegotiationConfigurer#favorParameter
ContentNegotiationConfigurer#favorPathExtension
```

If you set both to `false`, then Spring will look at the `Accept` header. Since your client can say `Accept: image/*,application/json` and handle both, Spring should be able to return either the image or the error JSON.

See [this Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) on content negotiation for more information and examples.

Comment: thanks for this excelent answer! on top of this, i removed setting of supported mediatypes in messageconverters and setting of contenttype in controller methods, so all is negotiated by spring. 
one more addition: to disable pathvariable-truncation use `matcher.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false)` in webconfig.

Comment: Your answer was on point. Changed to 1.9.2 and works like a charm

Comment: Beautiful Answer.

Comment: Referred tons of other SO questions related to this issue. Nothing else helped. Thanks a lot for clarifying. This sentence nails it - "By default, Spring looks at the extension rather than the Accept header."

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to your HTTP Accept header.
For example, if your controller produces "application/octet-stream" (in response), your Accept header should NOT be "application/json" (in request):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void download(HttpServletResponse response) {}
```

Comment: @Adam I suppose the client will accept any mime type in this case. Try it for yourself using tools like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: How can we do it in Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE when using `@GetMapping` ?

Comment: @PAA I'm using `@GetMapping`. is my answer not compatible with Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE?