# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation. When with special url

Tags: spring-mvc

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/servers/{domain}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Server getMailServer(@PathVariable("domain") String domain)

    Server server = null;
    try {
        server = getServerByDomain(domain);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
     return server;
    }
```

When I call "http://localhost:8080/server/hotmail.com" with HttpClient Get method,the value of variable domain is "hotmail", not "hotmail.com".And I got the error:
        HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation.

But if I call "http://localhost:8080/server/hotmail", it works well.

I hope someone can see what is causing this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation in exceptionhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351142/httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-could-not-find-acceptable-representation-in)

Answer (score 2):

This might be the same issue I had (and also this guy: https://stick2code.blogspot.co.at/2014/03/solved-orgspringframeworkwebhttpmediaty.html)

My service offers operations on files, i.e., /files/check/foo.txt

I always got a HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException and my rest handler was never actually called.

The problem is, that Spring has a feature where it tries to detect the requested content type by the path extension. So .com could mean a COM File. (See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-content-negotiation and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-path-matching)

My minimal @Config fix:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class PathDispatchConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `@RequestMapping` to following:)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/servers/{domain:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I had usernames (=mail adresses) in my request url. Thanks to the post of Benjamin Maurer I found the problem. However, I fixed it in a different way because I was unsure of the consequences regarding security of his answer.
I added the usernames as request parameters in the request. In your case, this would look something like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/servers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Server getMailServer(@RequestParam("domain") String domain) {
        // do stuff
    }
```

The request url would then look something like:
http://localhost:8080/server?domain=hotmail.com